# Update with "with data as" clause and regex do not commit. Why?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Sorry for the delay! I've taken a workload greater then i can handle these couple weeks.
Ok, lets clarify things up! 
 There is a proprietary software running on top of it and
I do not have de ability to change this software! Actually it allows me to do a few things.
In this specific case I can not create a relation 1>N, I can not create a new table! What I do can is create fields. 
So, how do i customize things? Through the database! Using triggers, functions and procedures. I know its a bad "work around" but it's what i got and works flawlessly 99% of times. Any exception my code throws the application shows on the screen!

The problem is actually the update not working.

You ask:
Why you're looping when you're forcing there to only be one iteration (unless P_QTDLINHAS can be < 1 I suppose?)
R: Couse the user can select multiple lines in the application but I dont want them to do it. So a throw an error on the screen.
Why you have nested begin/end blocks.
R: Couse I may have to throw exceptions, I got used to write begin Statements Exception some message end.

Sample data:

    `CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_DATA 
    (
      PKNUMBER      NUMBER NOT NULL 
    , DESCRIPTION   VARCHAR2(20) 
    , GROUPTOCHANGE VARCHAR2(100) 
    , STATUS        VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
    , CONSTRAINT SAMPLE_DATA_PK PRIMARY KEY 
      (
        PKNUMBER 
      )
      ENABLE 
    );`

```
INSERT INTO sample_data  VALUES (1000,'ORDER1',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO sample_data  VALUES (2000,'ORDER2',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO sample_data  VALUES (3000,'ORDER3',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO sample_data  VALUES (4000,'ORDER4','1000,2000,30001',NULL);
```

In this case the field GROUPTOCHANGE will be filled by the user like this "2108,8090,8843". Each number represents a PKNUMBER in same table "SAMPLE_DATA".

yes i know! the user can type something wrong.. let's ignore this for now!

The field STATUS will eventually be updated to 'C','L','R' OR NULL. When this happens I Need this logic to be executed:

`IF  OLD.STATUS <> NEW.STATUS AND GROUPTOCHANGE IS NOT NULL THEN`

```
UPDATE SAMPLE_DATA SP 
SET SP.STATUS = :NEW.STATUS 
WHERE SP.PKNUMBER IN (:NEW.GROUPTOCHAGE) 
AND PS.GROUPTOCHANGE IS NULL;

END IF;
```

Dispite the bad design is it possible to do? 
Thank for any help!!

Here what I've done so far:

    `create or replace PROCEDURE "AD_LIBERA_FRETES_FILHOS"(
                                                        P_CODUSU NUMBER, 
                                                        P_IDSESSAO VARCHAR2, 
                                                        P_QTDLINHAS NUMBER, 
                                                        P_MENSAGEM OUT VARCHAR2) 
    AS`

```
P_NUNOTA NUMBER(10);
P_CONTROLE VARCHAR(100);
P_PEDIDOS VARCHAR(100);
P_STATUS  VARCHAR(100);

BEGIN 
-- avoid more than 1 at a time
    IF (P_QTDLINHAS > 1) THEN 
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'SELECIONE APENAS UM PEDIDO PARA EXECUTAR ESTA AÇÃO.');

    END IF;


    FOR I IN 1..P_QTDLINHAS LOOP 
--extract param from session
        P_NUNOTA := ACT_INT_FIELD(P_IDSESSAO, I, 'PKNUMBER');
        P_STATUS := ACT_TXT_FIELD(P_IDSESSAO, I, 'STATUS');

--verify typed text should be "84090,89830,83393..."     
        BEGIN
            SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(CAB.GROUPTOCHANGE, '[0-9-, ]', ''),
                    CAB.GROUPTOCHANGE 
            INTO    P_CONTROLE,
                    P_PEDIDOS
            FROM SAMPLE_DATA CAB
            WHERE CAB.PKNUMBER = P_NUNOTA;

        END;

        IF (P_CONTROLE IS NOT NULL) THEN 

            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, '<B> SOMETHING WRONG !</B>');

        ELSE 

--perform de update (not working)

BEGIN
                UPDATE SAMPLE_DATA C
                SET C.STATUS = P_STATUS
                WHERE 
                C.GROUPTOCHANGE IS NULL AND
                C.PKNUMBER IN
                            (WITH DATA AS
                               (SELECT CAB.GROUPTOCHANGE STR
                                FROM SAMPLE_DATA CAB
                                WHERE CAB.PKNUMBER = P_NUNOTA ) 
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) STR
                             FROM DATA CONNECT BY INSTR(STR, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0);

            END;


        END IF;

END LOOP;

--mgs to show
P_MENSAGEM := 'DONE!! CHECK -> '||P_PEDIDOS;

END;
```

Comment: Please show your sample table data - including the linked rows - as formatted text, and include how you are calling the procedure, and the output you get. You might want to add debugs to checks what's happening (e.g. the values get get for `P_NUMOTA` and `P_STATUS`). Also, not sure why you're looping when you're forcing there to only be one iteration (unless `P_QTDLINHAS` can be < 1 I suppose?), or why you have nested begin/end blocks. The update doesn't need to be in an `else` either, as the raise will stop execution.

Comment: did you check the where clause in update statement?

Comment: If the question is why it does not commit, I have to ask, did you actually called a commit after executing it? If you are asking because the update itself doesn't work, that's a different thing. Also, you have a really bad design, you should have a relation table 1-n instead of that field `TGFCAB.AD_FRETEAGLUTINADO` that would be a lot easier to maintain and you wouldn't need a procedure to do this at all. Again if the problem is the update not working, show some sample data.